# Unable to Compile LinPhone on mac Xcode8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, linphone

Am trying to compile linphone for iphone but with no luck showing error for this code :

here :

```
 size_t count = bctbx_list_size(linphone_core_get_proxy_config_list(LC));
```

here:

```
? bctbx_list_index(linphone_core_get_proxy_config_list(LC), linphone_core_get_default_proxy_config(LC))
```

and here :

```
LinphoneProxyConfig *proxy = bctbx_list_nth_data(linphone_core_get_proxy_config_list(LC),
```

error :

```
/Users/araby/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/SideMenuTableView.m:105:24: Incompatible pointer types passing 'MSList *' (aka 'struct _MSList *') to parameter of type 'bctbx_list_t *' (aka 'struct _bctbx_list *')
```

and this also

```
/Users/araby/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/CallSideMenuView.m:150:100: No member named 'rtp_remote_family' in 'struct _LinphoneCallStats'


/Users/araby/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/CallSideMenuView.m:72:91: Use of undeclared identifier 'LinphoneAddressFamilyInet'
```

what happen and any idea to solve this so i can compile it ? i had 2 days searching with no luck at all

Comment: If you have followed their instructions to compile, and still experience this problem, I suggest you post an issue in their github issue tracker. https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/issues Good luck!

Comment: i just do like they say step by step and still showing same error . so i think the project have something missing ..

thanks javier

Comment: Then don't hesitate in letting them know :)